# Find the mode for a pandas column based on filtering on another pandas column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks similar to this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006]
                  'resolution_modified': ['It is recommended to replace scanner',
                                          'It is recommended to replace scanner',
                                          'It is recommended to replace laptop',
                                          'It is recommended to replace laptop',
                                          'It is recommended to replace printer',
                                          'It is recommended to replace printer'],
                   'cluster':[1,1,2,2,3,3]})
```

I want to find the string in `resolution_modified` that occurs the most for each unique `cluster` such that I will have a map where the key is the cluster and the value would be the mode string in the `resolution_modified` column.

This is what I have tried

```
# Get the string that occurs the most for each unqiue cluster
mode_string = {}
for cluster in hardware['cluster'].unique():
    if hardware[hardware['cluster']==cluster]:
        mode_string[cluster] = hardware['resolution_modified'].mode()[0]
mode_string
```

This did not work and throws an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pandas.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html):

```
mode_string = df.groupby("cluster")["resolution_modified"].agg(pd.Series.mode)

#cluster
#1       It is recommended to replace scanner
#2       It is recommended to replace laptop
#3       It is recommended to replace printer
```

You can also convert it to `dict`

```
mode_string = mode_string.to_dict()

#{1: 'It is recommended to replace scanner', 2: 'It is recommended to replace laptop', 3: 'It is recommended to replace printer'}
```

In both cases you can do:

```
mode_string[1]
#'It is recommended to replace scanner'
```

Answer (score 1):

The pandas way of doing that is to group by *cluster* and find the mode of *resolution_modified*:

```
res = df.groupby('cluster')['resolution_modified'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
mode_string = res.to_dict()
print(mode_string)
```

**Output**

```
{1: 'It is recommended to replace scanner', 2: 'It is recommended to replace laptop', 3: 'It is recommended to replace printer'}
```

See more on the documentation of [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) and [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html).

As an alternative, you could use [statistics.mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode):

```
from statistics import mode
res = df.groupby('cluster')['resolution_modified'].agg(mode)
```